# Stop row of divs dropping over to the next line within the wrapper

Tags: css, html

So I have a row of divs 3 infact which all float left and have equal amounts of margin between, however when it comes to the 3rd or right hand one if I put too much margin it forces it down to the next line naturally. I want it to sit slush within the wrapper so there is equal amounts is space between each one...

```
#mainwrapper .box {
    width: 288px;
    height: 245px;
    border:0px solid #fff;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #d9d9d9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #d9d9d9;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #d9d9d9;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: 10px solid #fff;

}

#mainwrapper .box img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
        -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
        -o-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-out; 
    transition: all 500ms ease-out;

}
```

So there is the wrapper for the image and the image - the wrapper it sits in is:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 980px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

Any ideas? Also users upload images to the list grows so it cannot be just applied to these three images...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. You want an unlimited number of divs to fit in a 980px box without wrapping?

Comment: Do you want the images to resize so that they all fit?

Comment: @quoo no I have my wrapper which is 960px wide within the wrapper three divs with images of users uploads appear but the problem is I want the 3 divs sit nicely within the wrapper with an even margin so flush to either side...but if I ut a margin on the right it forces the 3rd div down to the next line but if not enough margin it sits to far in and not flush with the right edge of the div...

Comment: @Austen Kind of yes...

Comment: You'll probably need to use javascript to do that. If you're using jQuery I'd be willing to help out.

Comment: Hi Austen, do you have skype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need css like this

```css
#wrapper .box {
    width: 30%;
    margin:0 5% 20px 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    /* your style here */
}
#wrapper .box:nth-child(3n) {margin:0 0 20px 0;}
```

IE8 don't understand :nth-child, you need to add some jquery

```
$('#wrapper .box:nth-child(3n)').addClass('third');
```

and separated css-rule

```css
#wrapper .box.third {margin:0 0 20px 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I would use the `:first-child` or `:last-child` (or nth-child) psuedo classes to remove the margin from the first element (or 3rd). nth-child would be the best choice as it'd allow you to keep adding divs, removing the margin from the 3rd image each time, but it's not well supported, so I'll show you an example using first-child.

```
#mainwrapper .box {
    width: 288px;
    height: 245px;
    border:0px solid #fff;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #d9d9d9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #d9d9d9;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #d9d9d9;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: 10px solid #fff;

}
#mainwrapper .box:first-child{
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: So in theory the the third or last should show no margin to the right of it? When I apply this is just takes over the entire div and takes away the margin.